# Need help for a 3x3 tic-tac-toe game's design. I can't get rid of some space in CSS

Tags: html, css

The design goal would be just to perfectly fit all div.tile into the div#gameField. My jQuery works fine, but than I got this CSS mess. Please tell me where the unwanted space, margin or padding comes from, because I have no more idea. I don't think it's the cause, but I use this one [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.2/normalize.css) too.

HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
        <div id="gameField">
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
        </div>

        <!--jQuery-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS3:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
}

#gameField {
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid darkgrey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

#gameField .tile {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: make a fiddle. and whats in your app.js?

Comment: add `font-size:0` to `#gameField` which will remove `whitespace` between `inline-block` elements and add `font-size` to `.title` if you need

Comment: and use `box-sizing:border-box` which takes  `border`, `padding` from inside

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` for `#gamefield .title` aligned them in a 3x3 order, but I needed `font-size: 0` also to perfectly fit into the `#gameField` div. Thanks [Vitorino fernandes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4025556/vitorino-fernandes)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to increase 300px width from 302px because border takes space.  Now your border is 1px therefore it take space inside. Hope it will fix your problem.